# Stripe Invoice Partial Payments

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to model a Stripe subscription where the collection method is send_invoice. However, I want to allow the customer to choose the amount they pay (ad-hoc, I believe its called), and then mark the invoice as paid when the total balance is received.

I can see that this is an option for ACH credit payments but only to handle mistakes from the customer. Is there any way to enable this for card payments on invoices too?

Comment: If you are looking for an integration where your customers can pay the invoices they will create by choosing from your products on Stripe, with the payment methods supported by Stripe, take a look at this --> https://easypie.shop

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible using Stripe out of the box. The Stripe hosted form for an Invoice does not allow the customer to input an amount of their choice. The amount listed on the Invoice is based on the parameters provided when creating the Invoice via the API.

You would need to create your own recurring logic to do the following as long as the full amount is not yet paid :

- Get the ad-hoc amount your customer would like to pay. This would have to be via your own custom created form
- Then [create an Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create) for that ad-hoc amount
- You would use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to listen for the [invoice.paid](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.paid) event to verify that the invoice is paid successfully. From the event details, you can retrieve the Invoice details and “link” it to the amount owed in the database for that customer.
- Calculate the amount left unpaid

**Example  - I have a customer that owes me $100**

- Ask the customer how much they would like to pay. Customer decides that they want to pay $10.
- Create an Invoice for $10.
- After the invoice is successfully paid. Tie the Invoice details to the amount owed in the database.
- Calculate the amount left.

Since there is still $90 left,

- Ask the customer how much they would like to pay. Customer decides that they want to pay $90.
- Create an Invoice for $90.
- After the invoice is successfully paid. Tie the Invoice details to the amount owed in the database.
- Calculate the amount left.

Mark the amount as fully paid in your database.